# Tomber en français

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, synonymes

J'aimerai savoir pourquoi la langue française utilise *tomber* à tort et à travers et quelle est l'origine de cette utilisation.

Si le sens premier de tomber correspond à chuter, on dit pourtant:

- Tomber amoureux, tomber enceinte (devenir)
- Qu'un événement nous est tombé dessus (être arrivé)
- Que quelque chose ou quelqu'un tombe à pic (ou du ciel) (arrive de façon opportune)
- Que quelque chose ou quelqu'un tombe mal (arrive de façon inopportune)
- De laisser tomber (abandonner)
- Qu'on est tombé sur quelqu'un (rencontrer)
- Qu'on est tombé sur la bonne réponse (trouver)
- Tomber des nues (être très surpris)
- ...

Plus rarement j'ai aussi entendu *si ça se tombe* au lieu de *si ça se trouve*.
As a rule of "thumb", peut-on m'expliquer pourquoi tomber a été choisi pour toutes ces actions en français ?

Comment: Il aurait fallu avant de poser la question faire une étude sur plusieurs langues pour dégager la ou les expressions pour lesquelles l'utilisation de tomber est spécifique au français. Dire que dans toutes les expressions citées le verbe « tomber » est utilisé « à tort et à travers » est un jugement péremptoire qui demanderait à être justifié. D'autres langues utilisent leur équivalent de tomber pour exprimer certaines de ces mêmes actions, (*aus allen Wolken fallen*, *fall in love*, *just drop it*) pour les premières qui me viennent à l'esprit dans l'immédiat.

Comment: Le mot *tomber* n'a pas été **choisi**. La langue évolue naturellement, et les mots évoluent par métaphore. Il n'y a rien d'exceptionnel ici.

Answer (score 6):

C'est le résultat du mouvement d'abandon à la gravitation déclenché par une impossibilité de résister à cette chute, ou de n'avoir pas su la prévenir.

D'une origine physique, le mot est devenu le symbole de ce qui nous arrive lorsque nous oublions par aveuglement ou par mégarde de nous tenir droit, vertical.

Cela peut être le fait du hasard et des circonstances.

Il y a là moyen de lier toutes les nuances que vous avez évoqué dans votre question.

Le fait de tomber indique que l'on va de haut en bas, donc une régression dans certains cas, une perte de liberté ou d'autonomie dans d'autres cas ou encore une découverte que l'on fait parce qu'on ne pouvait pas apercevoir ou comprendre la situation vue d'en haut.